# Wordpress use results of an external query in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom php page outside of wordpress, this page is connecting also to a external database, and get resultat form a sql query on a variable

i use `require('../wp-blog-header.php')` and `require('../wp-load.php')` to integrate with wordpress.

now i need to use this variable on the functions.php of my wordpress theme.

i do on my external page :

```
<head>
<connect to my database>
<my query>
<get resulte on $variable>
<require('../wp-blog-header.php')>
<require('../wp-load.php')>
```

but when i use $variable on my functions.php it do not work ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include wp-load.php alone. It will load wp-include (and wpdb), plugins and your theme (functions.php). To use the database directly you would do this:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->get_results('select ...');
```

If you need to access variable declared in functions.php, it's straight forward:

## say.php

```
<?php
include 'var.php';
print_r( $moo );
?>
```

## var.php

```
<?php
$moo= 'cow';
?>
```

## output of say.php

```
$ php say.php 
cow
```

Loading (include or require) functions.php after wp-load.php will result in redeclaration of the functions defined within functions.php (it will be loaded twice), causing PHP to crash.

Comment: thank's but i don't need a variable declared in functions.php, my variable and my database is external of wordpress. so i need to use an external variable on functions.php, this variable is a result of a query to an external database not the wordpress database

Comment: I modified the title of your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using wordpress features in your external query there is no need to include wordpress files.

Your external.php could look something like

```
function handy_prefix_my_processing_function() 
{

    //connect to database...
    //Do something with data...

    $result = $results

    //return the result
    return $result;

}
```

then in functions.php

```
function handy_prefix_get_my_variable() 
{
    //Load the external file and make its functions available
    include_once( 'external.php' );

    //Get my result
    $result = handy_prefix_my_processing_function();

    //Do something with the result....

}
```